# PrimeNG dropdown - disable certain SelectItems

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

Is there an option to disable **some** of PrimeNG's dropdown items (SelectItems)?

I notice [this discussion](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/586), is something changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is my workaround:

1)
extend original [`SelectItem`'s interface](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/selectitem.ts) ([reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces)) with `disabled` property, so merged interface will look like

```
interface SelectItem {
  label: string;
  value: any;
  disabled: boolean;
}
```

this may be done by declaring new interface with the same name:

```
interface SelectItem {
  disabled: boolean;
}
```

2)
based on `p-dropdown` [component's template](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts#L20), modify this part of template:

```
<li *ngFor="let option of optionsToDisplay;let i=index" 
    [ngClass]="{'ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all':true, 'ui-state-highlight':(selectedOption == option), 
                        'ui-dropdown-item-empty':!option.label||option.label.length === 0}"
    (click)="onItemClick($event, option)">
  <span *ngIf="!itemTemplate">{{option.label||'empty'}}</span>
  <ng-template [pTemplateWrapper]="itemTemplate" 
               [item]="option" 
               *ngIf="itemTemplate"></ng-template>
</li>
```

by adding `disabled: option.disabled` to `li`'s `ngClass` directive, so when option is set to disabled, 'disabled' CSS class will be added to the `il` element.
Also, `onItemClick($event, option)` should not be triggered by clicking on disabled options, and `itemClick` flag should be set to true, which will prevent dropdown closing. This can be achieved by rewriting the click function to

```
(click)="!option.disabled && onItemClick($event, option) || itemClick = true"
```

dropdown closing is done by [`onMouseclick($event)` function](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts#L334), which has following condition:

```
if (!this.itemClick) {
  ...
}
```

so, setting `itemClick` flag true for disabled options will prevent dropdown closing when clicking on disabled items.

This may be done by using [metadata reflection API](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-4). Import `Dropdown` class and get its metadata:

```
import { DropdownModule, Dropdown, SelectItem } from 'primeng/primeng';

...

// modify dropdown component's template
Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', Dropdown).forEach(annotation => {
  if (annotation.constructor.name === 'DecoratorFactory') {
    // add 'disabled' CSS class for disabled options
    annotation.template = annotation.template.replace("'ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all':true, ", "'ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all':true, disabled: option.disabled, ");
    // do not trigger click function on disabled options and set itemClick flag to prevent dropdown closing
    annotation.template = annotation.template.replace('(click)="onItemClick($event, option)"', '(click)="!option.disabled && onItemClick($event, option) || itemClick = true"');
  }
});
```

3)
add desired CSS for disabled items, for example:

```
.ui-dropdown-item.ui-corner-all.disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

That is it :) 
Tested on primeng@4.1.2

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/0Pqq565BPowABUauW7Y7

Comment: It's perfect!. Thank so much

Comment: it may not work as expected with AOT builds, so check it carefully when using AOT. I will post update to my answer when will have a chance to check it

Comment: We "extract" the dropdown component and edit it in local. So now for dropdowns we use our own component based in the primng component. (Only need to changes all his references like ../shared/common, etc.)

Comment: My dropdown is not displayed in page load, it is loaded when another drop down is selected. What I have to do to achieve this in that case?

Comment: please create a olunker showing your issue and I will try to help with non-metadata solution

Comment: The plunker doesn't seems to be working @Andriy
https://plnkr.co/edit/0Pqq565BPowABUauW7Y7

Answer (score 14):

You can also disable any item in primeng dropdown using ng-template, click event and custom style as below:

```
    cars: any[];
    selectedCar: string;
```

1. Initialize the cars array of object that is essentially an extension of Interface SelectItem with added property **disabled: boolean**

   ```
    ngOnInit(): void {
     this.cars = [];
     this.cars.push({label: 'Audi', value: 'Audi'});
     this.cars.push({label: 'BMW', value: 'BMW'});
     this.cars.push({label: 'Fiat', value: 'Fiat', disabled: true});
     this.cars.push({label: 'Ford', value: 'Ford'});
     this.cars.push({label: 'Honda', value: 'Honda', disabled: true});
     this.cars.push({label: 'Jaguar', value: 'Jaguar'});
     this.cars.push({label: 'Mercedes', value: 'Mercedes'});
     this.cars.push({label: 'Renault', value: 'Renault'});
     this.cars.push({label: 'VW', value: 'VW'});
     this.cars.push({label: 'Volvo', value: 'Volvo'});
    }
   ```
2. Method that gets triggered on click event

   ```
    onClick(disabled: boolean) {
            if(disabled) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
   ```
3. Customizing the Primeng Dropdown using ng-template and adding ng-style

   ```
    <p-dropdown [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar" [style]="{'width':'150px'}">
            <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
                <div>
                    <div (click)="onClick(option.disabled)" [ngStyle]="option.disabled? {'color': '#ccc', 'cursor': 'default'} : ''"> {{option.label}} </div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </p-dropdown>
   ```

**Credit: [ogousa](https://forum.primefaces.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=98629&sid=c04ffe7fbcf344e84bc2586c8e5e89d7) (primeng forum)**

Comment: solution is awesome but require some changes in default style that I did and it's working fine

Comment: to expand on what @TheParam said. You can use ngClass to add "disabled" class on the div. In CSS, clear default padding, hover, highlight styles from .ui-list-item, and then apply them to that div instead.