# SelectItem disabled property not working?

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I am using primeNG v7.0.3 and i'd like to disable some option in a multiselect component.
However I did everything as mentioned in the documentation it's still selectable as an option.
`[options]="roleOptions"` and initialized as: `roleOptions: SelectItem[];` then later populated with a function called by `ngOnInit`.

If need more clarification let me know.

How can I disable some of my options conditionally in a p-multiselect component?

**@Edit:**

What I've tried so far:
[This issue here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429868/8939031)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.translateInit().then(() => {
      this.setStatusOptions();
      this.setUserRoles();
    });
    this.setEditing();
  }

private setUserRoles() {
    this.roleOptions = [
      { label: this.messages['GLOBAL.USER.ROLE.CLINIC_USER'], value: this.roleEnum.CLINICUSER, disabled: true },
      { label: this.messages['GLOBAL.USER.ROLE.AGENT_USER'], value: this.roleEnum.AGENTUSER },
      { label: this.messages['GLOBAL.USER.ROLE.ADMIN_USER'], value: this.roleEnum.ADMINUSER },
      { label: this.messages['GLOBAL.USER.ROLE.CLINIC_REVIEWER'], value: this.roleEnum.CLINICREVIEWER }
    ];
  }
```

If I try the solution that I've linked I'll get the following:
[image]

**@Edit2 /SOLUTION/:**

In the template you need to remove optionLabel="label" in order to use this method now it's disabled. However the documentation should mention this I think.

Fun fact! You don't need the above mentioned solution for this to work, simply remove optionLabel from template and it's working...

Comment: can you please post sample code that you have tried

Comment: @Anusha_Mamidala added and Edit in the description

Comment: I see you use `this.roleOptions` but `[options]="selectOptions"`. Is this a typo in the question?

Comment: @PierreDuc it was, now it's fixed. It'd not even show correctly if i'd do that.

Comment: have you really tried the answer you linked? catching and canceling the click event?

Comment: @PierreDuc made an edit again to paste a proof. It even screws over the placement of the items(chackbox+label), but nontheless it's still not disabled, you can click it as you'd like.