# how to disable specific select item in prime ng dropdown?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have an `angular` app in which i have `primeNg dropdown` like this

```
 <p-dropdown class="ml-4 mt-2" styleClass="p-zero" optionLabel="name" dataKey="name" placeholder="Select Matrix"
  [options]="partPricings" (onChange)="handleDropdownSelect($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedPart">
</p-dropdown>
```

`component.ts'

```
this.partPricings = [
  {
     type: "part"
     default: false
     isInActive: false
     _id: "5e80a39db0f2323bb861006f"
     name: "Default Pricing"
     items: [{min: 0, max: 310, markup: 23}]
  },
        {
     type: "part"
     default: false
     isInActive: false
     _id: "5e80a39db0f2323bb861006g"
     name: "Test Matrix"
     items: []
  }
]
```

Now i want to `disable` some specific select item in `dropdown`. So how can i do this?

Comment: You can take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43873162/1009922).

Comment: i am confused about that how i extend `selectItem` interface according to my data?

Comment: The other answer maybe simpler to implement.

Comment: yes second answer is simple. But in second answer he is making is data set like `{label : ' ', value : ' ', disabled : true}` but in my case my data set is not like this. Mine is like this
`{type : 'part', default : false,... rest of the keys}` so should i add another key in this object named `disabled`?

Comment: Using his code, you can replace the occurrences of `option.disabled` by `option.isInActive`.

Comment: yes got the solution. Thank you