# Angular Reactive form disable specific options in p-dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

Using PrimeNg p-dropdown in component.

```
<p-dropdown 
 [options]="productRequest"
 formControlName="request"
 optionLabel="ProductName"
 (onChange)="someFunction('request')">
</p-dropdown>
```

Below is the JSON received from server that is used as `[options]` in p-dropdown

```
{ 
 "Increase": true,
 "Decrease" : true,
 "Like" : true,
 "Dislike" : true,
 "Old" : false,
 "Others" : true
}
```

I need to disable that option against which `boolean: false` is mentioned.
Like while i click on dropdown, i am able to see all options. Now i need to disable that particular option against which `boolean: false` is mentioned.
In above case i should be able to select all options except `Old` as it has `boolean: false` against it.

How to do so ??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PrimeNG dropdown - disable certain SelectItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873162/primeng-dropdown-disable-certain-selectitems)

Comment: @Eldar: Unable to identify actually what that workaround is, hence unable to implement it. If possible can you please tell me what it's saying.

Comment: Any way @Eldar: to get specific dropdown option property on page load or on mouseclick as soon as we click to see list of options ?? If I get it, I can apply disable attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable specific options using the dropdown component of prime-ng, you must use SelectItem type when constructing your array.

Within the SelectItem type there is a disabled property of type boolean.

This is where you can disable a specific option by setting this property to true.

I have created you a Stackblitz with a working example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-m6a6ni

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Unable to include that workaround in my case.. As per your reference I just need to add <ng-template> and option.disabled, but it's not working for me

Comment: Any way to get specific dropdown option property on page load or on mouseclick as soon as we click to see list of options. There I can apply disable attribute to that option

Comment: @rose - no need to work around , solution is in the updated the answer for you :-)

Comment: thanks very much it solved my query, hence marking it as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a field in your productRequest models as a boolean like isDisable and use it like the below example.

```
optionDisabled="isDisable"

<p-dropdown 
 [options]="productRequest"
 formControlName="request"
 optionLabel="ProductName"
 optionDisabled="isDisable"
 (onChange)="someFunction('request')">
</p-dropdown>
```

`productRequest = "[{ name: 'Increase', isDisable: true}, { name: 'Old', isDisable: false}]"`